# Can drush accept piped commands for aliases?

Tags: drush, multi-sites

Can drush take piping commands for a multisite command using an alias?

I'm trying to setup a simple refresh function from my prod to dev/staging. Any pointers or tips would be welcome. just started learning this stuff.

```
drush $prodalias sql-dump --gzip >/tmp/$site.sql.gz

gunzip /tmp/$site.sql.gz | drush $devalias sqlc
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be allowed to use piping in drush aliases as this feature was added recently by [improving escaping options for core-exec](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/954).

So you have to upgrade your drush to the recent version (7.x).

See: [Are pipes allowed in shell aliases?](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/897)

---

If you prefer to use script, here is one which I'm usually using:

```
#!/bin/sh
# pull-db.sh
# Script to pull the database from remote to local environment.
[ -z "$1" ] && { echo "Usage: $0 @remote (args)"; exit 1; }
SRC="$1"
shift
drush $SRC sql-dump | drush $* sql-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

I write bash/shell scripts involving Drush all the time. If it's just the variables you're interested in, that has nothing to do with Drush and works fantastically. As for piping, I i'm not too sure what all is supported.

For bash to interpret your variables, you just need to wrap them in quotes.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
source=$1
dest=$2

# Check if we have both a source and a destination.
if [ -z "$dest"]; then
  # Looks like at least one of our parameters are missing, notify and exit.
  echo "A source and destination Drush alias is required."
  exit 1
fi    

drush sql-sync "$source" "$dest"
```

Usage:

```
./my-sync-script.sh @alias.prod @alias.dev
```